# SQLite join command 4 tables

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, join

I'm little noobie in sql and i want some help.
I have 3-4 tables and i want to make an sqlite command to return me some rows. The tables are the following.

**Table: Restaurant**

```
| Name | menuID | REFERENCES [Menu]([menuID])|
```

**Table: Menu**

```
| MenuID | Name |
```

**Table: Ingredient**

```
| IngredientID | Name |
```

**Table: Food_Incl_ingredient**

```
| FoodIncIngredientID | FoodID REFERENCES [Food][FoodID] | IngredientID REFERENCES [Ingredient]([IngredientID])|
```

**Table: Food**

```
| FoodID | Name | Type | MenuID REFERENCES [Menu][MenuID]|
```

I want to make a query to return me the name of the restaurant,the food name and the type of food if they don't have the ingredient i will say.
Thank you.

**Table Restaurant:**

```
| Name     | MenuId |
  Goodys        2
  Koumbaris     1
```

**Table Menu:**

```
| MenuID |     Name     |
    1      koumbarisMenu
    2      goodysMenu
```

**Table Food:**

```
| FoodID |     Name      |  Type  | MenuID |
   29     Chef's Salad    Starter     2
   31     Mama's Salad    Starter     2
   30     Ceasar's Salad  Starter     2
```

Table Food_Incl_ingredient:

```
| FoodInclIngredientID | FoodID | IngredientID |
          1               29           1
          6               31           1
          8               30           1
```

**Table Ingredient:**

```
| IngredientID |  Name  |
    1         Cereals
    2         Shellfish
```

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT Restaurant.Name, Food.Name, Food.Type
FROM Restaurant
INNER JOIN Menu ON Restaurant.menuID = Menu.MenuID  
INNER JOIN Food ON Menu.MenuID = Food.MenuID  
INNER JOIN Food_Incl_ingredient ON Food.FoodID = Food_Incl_ingredient.FoodID  
INNER JOIN Ingredient ON Food_Incl_ingredient.FoodInclIngredientID = Ingredient.IngredientID  
WHERE Ingredient.Name == 'Cereals'
```

**Expected Results:**

```
| Name |      Name      |  Type  |
 Goodys  Chef's Salad     Starter
 Goodys  Mama's Salad     Starter
 Goodys  Ceasar's Salad   Starter
```

The only result i get is the first line.

Comment: Since you say you are new, I've heard good things about the book Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.  Learning the fundamentals will prevent a lot of fumbling about.

Comment: The part about not having an ingrediant is unclear.

Comment: Show some efforts from your side too. Here people are there for help provided you too work on the problem.

Comment: Oooops. This is a stupid one ;) ... Look at the 6th line of the query. You're joining `ON Food_Incl_ingredient.FoodInclIngredientID = ...` but instead you should join `ON Food_Incl_ingredient.IngredientID = ...`. And just a small note: Use `=` in the last line instead of `==`.

Comment: OMG! I can't believe it!
Thank you, thank you very much.
I can't believe i didn't see it. :)

Comment: There is another thing now. If i use (!=) there is a problem. For example a food have 5 ingredients. In the table Food_Incl_Ingredient i have this food 5 times with each ingredient. The query it will discard the first line which include the ingredient but it will show me the other four times this food because the ingredient does not much. How can i say it to discard completely this food because it already find an ingredient inside the food?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where's the problem? Just join all tables you need and afterwards say `WHERE Ingredient.Name != 'meat'`.

```
SELECT Restaurant.Name, Food.Name, Food.Type
FROM Restaurant
  JOIN Menu ON Restaurant.menuID = Menu.MenuID
  JOIN Food ON Menu.MenuID = Food.MenuID
  JOIN Food_Incl_ingredient ON Food.FoodID = Food_Incl_ingredient.FoodIncIngredientID
  JOIN Ingredient ON Food_Incl_ingredient.FoodIncIngredientID = Ingredient.Ingredient.ID
WHERE Ingredient.Name != 'meat'
```

I hope I understood what's a table name in your posting and what's the primary key ;)

Comment: Thank you for the help. The strange now is why it returns me only one food. In the database they are at least 10 food with ingredient Cereals that i have. I have make it to be equal to Cereals

Comment: In you question it looked like you wanted to have all the Restaurant+Food+Type which DON'T have the ingredient. ... My query gives you every food which doesn't contain meat ;) So if you wan't to have every food which contains meat, you have to use `==` instead of `!=` in the last line.

Comment: yes i have put == put is not correct. It return me only one Restaurant with a food and not 10 for example which contains the Cereals

Comment: and another question, why we choose FROM Restaurants and not other table?

Comment: basically you can choose `FROM` whatever you want. I just wanted to point out a clear `JOIN` structure: Restaurant -> Menu -> Food -> Food_Incl_ingredient -> Ingredient.

Comment: Ok, thank you again for the help. I will try to play little with this query and see if i could find something.

Comment: If i have wrong the PRIMARY KEYS and FOREIGN KEYS it wouldn't work or it's not necessary?

Comment: the query above will work even with wrong keys, because we use `ON x = y`, where we explicitly define which columns to choose for the `JOIN` operation.

Comment: So the problem is somewhere else. I really don't understand why it does not return me all the results and a few of them

Comment: Could you please write down an example table plus(!) the expected result? and the result you currently get maybe. this would make things a lot easier.

Comment: I have edit my question. You can see at above that i have put the tables with some data and what i expect.

Comment: There is another thing now. If i use (!=) there is a problem. For example a food have 5 ingredients. In the table Food_Incl_Ingredient i have this food 5 times with each ingredient. The query it will discard the first line which include the ingredient but it will show me the other four times this food because the ingredient does not much. How can i say it to discard completely this food because it already find an ingredient inside the food?

Answer (score 0):

`...if they don't have the ingredient i will say`

Here's a very basic structure to let you write a query to say *whether a restaurant needs to buy ingredients for its menu(s)*.

You would typically structure things so a restaurant could have more than one menu, e.g. breakfast, lunch, dinner, maybe catering or parties too.

Notice the LEFT JOIN and the use of COALESCE at the very end.

```
Restaurant
id
restaurantname

Menu
id
menuname   e.g. Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner, Catering, Party, Special Cultural Holiday

Dish
id
dishname   

Ingredient
id
ingredientname
```

-- a dish has one or more ingredients

```
Dish_Ingredients
dishid
ingredientid
```

-- a menu has one or more dishes

```
MenuDish
menuid
dishid
```

-- a restaurant has one or more menus

```
RestaurantMenu
restaurantid
menuid
```

-- a restaurant keeps an inventory of ingredients

```
RestaurantIngredients
restaurantid
ingredientid
quantityOnHand
```

-- left join will cause NULL values to be returned when dish calls for an ingredient that has no record in inventory; hence COALESCE()

```
    select restaurantname, menuname, dishname, ingredientname, quantityOnHand
    from restaurant R 
    inner join restaurantmenu RM on R.id = RM.restaurantid
    inner join menu M on RM.menuid = M.id
    inner join menudish MD on MD.menuid = M.id
    inner join dish D on MD.dishid = D.id
    inner join dishingredient DI on DI.dishid = D.id
    inner join ingredients I on DI.ingredientid  = I.id

    LEFT JOIN

    restaurantingredients RI  on RI.ingredientid = I.id and RI.restaurantid = R.id   
    where Coalesce(quantityOnHand, 'none') as CurrentInventory
```

Comment: little difficult to understand this complex query but i will try to manage what is this, thank you.

Comment: It isn't a complex query, really.  It's the same type of simple join happening several times with several tables, that's all.  Once you have understood the purpose of "linking" tables such MenuDish and DishIngredients, everything will become clear to you.